# "The system cannot find the file specified" when using SecureCRT SFTP to download file from Linux server to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, sftp, secure-crt

I want to download a file from my Linux server to my local Windows PC.
I used SecureCRT to build an SSH connection and then use SFTP `get` command to download, but failed:

```
sftp> get /remote/path/file.svg  D:\local\path
Downloading file.svg from /remote/path/file.svg
get: D:/local/path: The system cannot find the file specified.
  100% 39KB     39KB/s 00:00:00
/remote/path/file.svg: 40319 bytes transferred in 0 seconds (39 KB/s)
sftp>
```

I found out that it is possible to upload files from Windows to Linux.
But unable to download any file from Linux to windows
Very confused, I have tried many ways to solve this problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Secure CRT documentation for `get` does not say anything about possibility of specifying the target local path:
https://documentation.help/SecureCRT/SFTP_Tab_Command_Options.htm

You possibly need to `lcd` before:

```
lcd C:\target\local\path
get /source/remote/path/file.txt
```